# Splitting Cell into Multiple row using array

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to split the range of data like this :-

[image]

At first I was using this :-

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW($B$2:$B)>=(SUM($A$2:$A)+ROW()),"",IFERROR(SPLIT(LOOKUP(ROW($B$2:$B)-ROW(),IF(ROW($B$2:$B)>=(SUM($A$2:$A)+ROW()),"",SUMIF(ROW($A$2:$A),"<"&ROW($A$2:$A),$A$2:$A)),A2:A),""),"")))
```

But this didn't worked, I got this from another stack answer, I know this is not right :(, I can't reach anywhere with this

This is the sheet URL :- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oB1i0IAGoCVN0ynKBXDQcmEd3c_mpOdmWVFo7Gz-vyk/edit#gid=0

Thanks

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Formula for you**

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(CHAR(10),A2:A7),CHAR(10),1,0))
```

[image]

**Function References**

- [JOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en)
- [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

`REDUCE` the array by `SPLIT`ting by `CHAR(10)`:

| data | Intended Result |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
|  |  |
| 1 2 3 | 1 |
|  | 2 |
|  | 3 |

```
=REDUCE("Intended Result",A2:A5,LAMBDA(a,c,{a;IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(c,CHAR(10))))}))
```